# How to check if string starts with a number, latin letter or underscore

Tags: java, regex, string

Help me please to make regular expression that checks what was described in topic.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) some time. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Dumping a requirement then sitting on your hands, waiting for someone to write you code, is not what Stack Overflow wants to be for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
^[\\p{IsLatin}\\d_]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a character class:

```
if (str.matches("[0-9a-zA-Z_].*"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Or simply use shortcut  `\w` it's mean in java `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

```
^\\w.*
```

You can also change `^` to `\\A` if you want check the start of the string and not the start of the line

```
\\A\\w.*
```